# Android recorded aac(.mp3) file not playing in iOS

Tags: android, ios, swift, avplayer, android-mediarecorder

Hi I'm using the following code to record audio on Android

```
myRecorder = new MediaRecorder();
myRecorder.setAudioSource(MediaRecorder.AudioSource.MIC);
myRecorder.setOutputFormat(MediaRecorder.OutputFormat.MPEG_4);
myRecorder.setAudioEncoder(MediaRecorder.AudioEncoder.AAC);
myRecorder.setAudioSamplingRate(44100);
myRecorder.setAudioEncodingBitRate(256);
myRecorder.setAudioChannels(1);
voiceFileName = getFilename();
myRecorder.setOutputFile(voiceFileName);

private String getFilename() {
    String filepath = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getPath();
    File file = new File(filepath, "test");

    if (!file.exists()) {
        file.mkdirs();
    }
    return (file.getAbsolutePath() + "/" + System.currentTimeMillis() + ".mp3");

}
```

but that aac(.mp3) file does not play on iOS.
EDIT

```
let audioFilename = getDocumentsDirectory().stringByAppendingPathComponent("whistle.mp3")
let audioURL = NSURL(fileURLWithPath: audioFilename)
let whistlePlayer:AVAudioplayer = try AVAudioPlayer(contentsOfURL: audioURL)
whistlePlayer.play()
```

How do I  play this file in IOS(Swift)?

Comment: Your question is a bit unclear: Does the mp3 recording not play on iOS and Android both?

Comment: your question is related to android or iOS

Comment: hi i edited my qusetion added swit coding to play

Answer (score 4, accepted):

i got solution just changed extension to .m4a it work on ios

```
let audioFilename = getDocumentsDirectory().stringByAppendingPathComponent("voice.m4a")
let audioURL = NSURL(fileURLWithPath: audioFilename)
do
 {
   audioPlayer = try AVAudioPlayer(contentsOfURL: audioURL)
   audioPlayer.delegate = self
   audioPlayer.play()
 }
catch{
   print("filenotfound")
}
```

Comment: My files are stored in Server and they are .mp3 extension. Can AVPlayer be set to treat mp3 files as m4a?

Answer (score 1):

myRecorder.setOutputFormat(MediaRecorder.OutputFormat.MPEG_4); suggests you should have been writing to mp4 (m4a). Not sure aac can be written to mp3 container

Answer (score 0):

check if you can play that file in safari of iPhone. 
and can you tell how are you trying to play that file?

Comment: safari not play this mp3